# reverse engineering by "Uml-Designer"

Tags: uml, uml-designer

the very simple question: Is `UML Designer` able to execute the `reverse engineering` my classes  ?

I am reading currently the documentation from official page, but didn't meet any words about this feature.

regards

Comment: The documentation suggest that there is an add-on to generate code.  The fact that they do not mention the reverse engineering of code (which is more difficult to implement than code generation) strongly suggest that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As UML Designer is based on the Eclipse UML2 project you can install the Eclipse UML Gen plugins: https://www.eclipse.org/umlgen/

One of these plugins will allow you to get a reverse engineering tool.

These plugins are not part of UML Designer but I will try in the future to improve the installation. An issue already exists about this in our tracker : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/878